# Magento: What are the calculation rules inside orders and order_items tables?

Tags: magento

In one magento store that I am working at I got some problems with orders (the problem was generated by the fact that magento was by default rounding prices at a precision of 2 while 4 was necessary an taxes too).

I have fixed this problem so the new orders are stored with the corect sums, but there are some orders which need some recalculation.

One approach is to loop through orders and order_items table and set the correct sums.

But there are a lot of columns and some of them aren't very self speaking about what they represent (like hidden_tax_amount).

I know for sure that original_price and tax_percent are correct, then I have the quantities, so I belive some recalculations could be done easily, but only if I would know the rules.

So, do you know it?

Answer (score 0):

`Mage_Sales_Model_Quote` has a method `collectTotals()`. This method is used to calculate all the price and tax data. Orders are created based on quote (most of the data is just copied from quote to order). This is difficult to recalculate all order data.

You can take a look at `Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote` class and its method `submitOrder()`.

Or you can try to load order, then get its quote (`$order->getQuote()`), then run `collectTotals()` on `$quote` object. Finally in a `foreach` like loop you can copy desired values from quote to order. Don't forget to `save()` both objects.

Comment: This is the kind of approach I like! I will try this and come back with the result I get. Thank you!

Comment: So, seems like there is not a getQuote directly, but a getQuoteId instead. Only that when I try to get totals (and debug them to paint myself a picture) I get a 500 status - while looking in logs seems like magento tries to allocate over 2G memory :|

Comment: Yes, that's true with Magento. Objects are often huge, due to the all references inside them. Yet, there is a way in this madness! Almost all objects (especially models) in Magento inherit from `Varien_Object`. That object has this great method `debug()`, which will get you a string representation of the object's data! So, you can do something like `foreach ($quote->getTotals() as $total) { Mage::log($total->debug(), null, 'totals.log'); }`. Note that `debug()` prints only `$this->_data` array of the object. In most cases it's enough, though.